# KVM: virt-install "Unsupported sound model 'ich6'"

Tags: kvm-virtualization

Is it possible to add "Intel HD Audio" to a KVM VM with "virt-install" in Ubuntu 11.04? Using "kvm" could do this so I think it is only a problem of virt-install, maybe the script needs an update. On Fedora 15 "--soundhw ich6" works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is what you get:

```
$ lsb_release -sd
Ubuntu 11.04

$ qemu -soundhw help
Unknown sound card name `help'
Valid sound card names (comma separated):
pcspk       PC speaker
sb16        Creative Sound Blaster 16
ac97        Intel 82801AA AC97 Audio
es1370      ENSONIQ AudioPCI ES1370
hda         Intel HD Audio

-soundhw all will enable all of the above
```

So try -soundhw hda